# How to make jquery contains case insensitive on key up event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using jquery search from big static page using following code But this search act as case sensitive How can i change it to work for case insensitive also(ie Search music if user type MUSIC or music etc)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.searchbig').keyup(function(){
     searchedText = $('.searchbig').val();

     var $grid = $(".grid").show();
     if( searchedText ) {
     $grid.filter(":not(:contains('"+searchedText+"'))").hide();
      }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make the search case insensitive is to convert value to lowercase.

```
searchText = $(".searchbig").val().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Keep you data in upper case and keep user free to type

```
searchedText.toUpperCase()
```